# Trying to create a dialog in another thread wxpython

Tags: python, multithreading, dialog, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm running a function in another thread that is supposed to fill out a dialog and then show it but it just seg faults as soon as I tried to alter the dialog in any way. I've read that this is a common issue with WxPython and that devs are not intended to directly alter dialogs in another thread.

How do I get around this? I can just call the function in my main thread but that will block my GUI and it is a lengthy operation to initialize the dialog - I would like to avoid this.

My code is similar to the below.

### In the main thread

```
# Create the dialog and initialize it
thread.start_new_thread(self.init_dialog, (arg, arg, arg...))
```

### The function I am calling

```
def init_dialog(self, arg, arg, arg....):
  dialog = MyFrame(self, "Dialog")

  # Setup the dialog
  # ....
  dialog.Show()
```

Even with a blank dialog and just a simple call to show inside the function I get a segmentation fault. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It is not a good idea to to try and use GUI components on worker threads. Most GUI frameworks I think including wxPython do not work correctly when GUI components are used in this way. Indeed there is an article here about using wxPython with worker threads http://wiki.wxpython.org/Non-Blocking%20Gui

Comment: Use Container Class (class foo : pass), add,remove,update,call function merge your app.

Comment: Why not run the "length operation" in a separate thread, but then the dialog in the main thread?

Comment: @tom10 because the main thread would then have to wait for the operation to complete which is what I don't want. The operation generates a figure and the figure must be displayed in the dialog

Comment: Why would the main gui have to wait if you run the lengthy operation in a separate thread?

Comment: @tom10 Because the resulting figure must be added to the dialog's sizer when the generation is completed. I thought that after the figure is generated in the worker thread I could just add it to the gui from that thread, but this has proved to be impossible. Now what I am attempting to do is fire an event saying the figure has been generated and pass the figure in an event to a handler which puts together the dialog and shows it

Comment: The usual way to deal with this is to click a button in the main thread, do the calculation in a different thread (so that the main thread and GUI are still responsive), show an indicator (like a "throbber" in the main thread) that the calculation is being performed, and then pop up the dialog in the main thread when the calculation is completed.  That is, if you have to wait, then you wait, but you don't want to block the main thread or leave the user in the dark as to what's going on.

Comment: @tom10 and that is precisely what I'm doing now, using an event handler worked. thanks

Comment: @Riptyde4 event handlers will run on the same thread that sends the event. You'll want to use something like [`wx.CallAfter`](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter) if you have gui bits in the handler and the event is created from a background thread. That will push it onto the main thread.

Comment: @thor18 this is 5 months old

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made an applet to demonstrate keeping GUI responsive during calculations and calling the message box after the calculations.

```
    import wx
    import threading
    import time


    class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "I am a test frame")
            self.clickbtn = wx.Button(self, label="click me!")
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClick)

        def onClick(self, event):
            self.clickbtn.Destroy()
            self.status = wx.TextCtrl(self)
            self.status.SetLabel("0")
            print "GUI will be responsive during simulated calculations..."
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.runCalculation)
            thread.start()

        def runCalculation(self):
            print "you can type in the GUI box during calculations"
            for s in "1", "2", "3", "...":
                time.sleep(1)
                wx.CallAfter(self.status.AppendText, s)
            wx.CallAfter(self.allDone)

        def allDone(self):
            self.status.SetLabel("all done")
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
                                   "This message shown only after calculation!",
                                   "",
                                   wx.OK)
            result = dlg.ShowModal()
            dlg.Destroy()
            if result == wx.ID_OK:
                self.Destroy()

    mySandbox = wx.App()
    myFrame = TestFrame()
    myFrame.Show()
    mySandbox.MainLoop()
```

GUI stuff is kept in the main thread, while calculations continue unhindered. The results of the calculation are available at time of dialog creation, as you required.

Comment: Do we always need to call dlg.Destroy() after calling dlg.ShowModal()?

Comment: @masphei yes. But, this is all for the old wx "classic" stuff that's phased out. I think wx "Phoenix" works differently and unfortunately he didn't call it "wx2" so it's not always obvious what examples you are looking at.