# wxPython: only the main thread can process Windows messages error

Tags: python, wxpython

I found this error below when I execute my wxpython based UI for the second time.  The first time UI launched and closed, it does not have the error. But, if launched again and closed, then some errors show up as seen below.  I added some debug logs to see the thread names below. 
Does anyone have any idea what's wrong here?
In general,  I want to create new thread for the main form.

```
>>> import testui
>>> testui.run()
Launching TestUI thread...    
thread1 = MainThread
thread3 = Thread-11  
thread4 = Thread-11
thread2 = MainThread

>>> testui.run()
Launching TestUI thread...
thread1 = MainThread
thread3 = Thread-12
Exception in thread Thread-12:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "c:\python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "c:\test\testui.py", line 587, in ui_thread_function
apps.MainLoop()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 2096, in MainLoop
rv = wx.PyApp.MainLoop(self)
wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxThread::IsMain()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\evtloop.cpp(182) in 
wxGUIEventLoop::Dispatch(): only the main thread can process Windows messages

thread2 = MainThread
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
 import threading

 class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        ...

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

frmMainForm = None

class TestUIApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        global frmMainForm
        frmMainForm = MainFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(frmMainForm)
        frmMainForm.Show()
        frmMainForm.Center()
        return True

def ui_thread_function():
    print("Launching Test UI thread...\n")
    apps = TestUIApp(0)
    main_thread = threading.currentThread()

    print("thread3 = %s" % main_thread.getName())
    apps.MainLoop()
    main_thread = threading.currentThread()
    print("thread4 = %s" % main_thread.getName())

def run():
    x = threading.Thread(target=ui_thread_function)
    x.start()
    main_thread = threading.currentThread()
    print("thread1 = %s\n" % main_thread.getName())
    x.join()
    main_thread = threading.currentThread()
    print("thread2 = %s" % main_thread.getName())
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to use multiple threads *for GUI* in the wx framework.
See those two links for more information on how to use `wx.CallAfter` to asynchronically schedule GUI updates from workers into the main thread:

In python:
[Trying to create a dialog in another thread wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925256/trying-to-create-a-dialog-in-another-thread-wxpython)

In C++:
https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=40332

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running the 2nd pass in the same Python process as the first run. That means that you are creating more than one `wx.App` in a single process, which can sometimes work, but usually has problems of one sort or another. Also, you are creating a new thread for that 2nd `wx.App` and from wxWidget's perspective only the first thread that created the first `wx.App` is the "GUI thread".

So, if you follow the one `wx.App` per process, and one GUI thread per process[*] rule then you'll find that things work much better.

[*] Be aware that on OSX there are platform limitations that require the GUI thread to be the main thread.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me which lines of code that cause the problem?